# Would the following classes be relevant to a class diagram?

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I'm building a class diagram for a system where either `student`, `staff`, or a  `normal user` (someone who isn't registered as any part of the organisation, just a normal citizen) can purchase a food item from a machine.

When a `student` or `staff` accesses this machine they can swipe/scan their membership card which allocates them a discount. When a `normal user` makes a purchase no such membership card is used, they simply make the full priced payment.

My question is, would the class diagram contain classes for `student` and `staff`? Or, would all the information regarding these people simply be stored in a class called `membership card` which tells the system who the person is based on their card information?

I'm new to UML so this has confused me a bit. It seems like the student and staff member's information would be based off their membership card when it's scanned, so would classes for these types of people be necessary?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Who are you communicating this design to? What do they need to know to implement your idea in code?  That's what belongs in UML.  It's a notation for communication.  UML diagrams aren't engineering drawings.  Add what you'd want to see to be able to code the problem.  Don't worry about UML - no one cares about it much these days.

Comment: I'm revising for an exam which requires me to construct a class diagram, I understand UML isn't particularly ideal for many scenarios but I am still required to learn it and this was one of the practice questions. Does this mean the diagram is basically open to any interpretation? In other words there's kind of no right or wrong way of doing it as long as it makes general sense to an engineer?

Comment: By all means, construct a class diagram with student, staff, and user.  I assume that the first two will inherit from user.  No right or wrong?  Unfortunately that's correct.  Diagrams are a way to communicate your intent to other developers.  If they can understand it from the diagram you've done well.  If not, they'll ask questions and modify it.  Are you writing class and sequence diagrams?  Your description of a flow suggests the latter to me.

Comment: Yes, I was planning on them inheriting from 'customer'. The question asks for a class diagram only and whilst sequence diagrams are mentioned in our course I don't believe we are asked to draw one in the exam.

Answer (score 0):

Your vending machine needs to distinguish the different user types in some way. The identification is made by the card reader recognizing the member or guest card. This will for sure hold the information about the member/guest. If this is just to show "Pay X" you will not need any class for either since the information is already present on the read card. If members have some kind of account where the payment is taken from, then you need a class for the member to access the account.